# Laggy Windows, and cant install Post Release update driver

Tags: 11.10, drivers, graphics, proprietary, jockey

When I move my windows around they are really laggy. I had a feeling it's because Ubuntu isn't taking full advantage of my graphics card so i went to install the additional drivers. The normal proprietery one does nothing to help the window issue and everytime i try and install the post release update it says "Sorry Installation of this driver failed"

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the failed post-release update in the restricted drivers tool, but I have experienced the laggy windows and I read that you can un-tick "Sync to VBlank" in the OpenGL module in the General section of ccsm (if you don't have ccsm, sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager, then just run "ccsm").  I also read this affects mostly ATI cards.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ATI Graphics card, you can't install the post-release-update one because the fglrx-updates ubuntu package is broken (bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/949641)

I also got that problem.  So I went ahead and installed the normal one.  It does not fix the laggy windows on my computer, and it also caused my computer to become unstable. (Reported Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/995184)

So I'll just wait until the fglrx-updates package is fixed.  You'll able to install the post-release-update Driver.